# What to use? Integrate a front end Web App with XQuery/Saxon as the platform?

Tags: java, php, gwt, xquery, saxon

As a relative newbie to XQuery and Saxon I have inherited a few hundred XQuery modules that analyse automated regression test result files. There is one `.txt` test result file per test case. There is also one XQuery `.XQ` module per regression test case.

Basically each XQuery module `.XQ` takes a set of raw test data encoded in XML format as input, runs analysis and generates an HTML table displaying PASS/FAIL type results.

Currently control of this suite is via a set of DOS `.BAT` files, one per test case. From within each `.BAT` an external parser `.exe` encodes a raw test result file from `.txt` format into `.xml` format and then runs the specific XQuery module for the test case using `Saxon.jar` as the processor. The '.bat' file finishes by launching an instance of Explorer to display the final HTML file containing the results table.

Essentially the above process is very manual and requires each case to be run individually using the .BAT files. I need an improved architecture from which to control and present the analysis of these test result files using the set of XQuery modules I currently have. The process of executing an analysis would inlvolve

- Loading/storing a set of raw test result files in `.txt` format
- Converting raw test result files to XML using the external parser `.exe`
- Initiating the suite of XQuery modules using Saxon to analyse the `.xml` result files
- Produce display the tabulated results

So my question is in order to achieve integration of the above process, assuming I replace the `.bat` files, what are the ideal tools I should be considering that will hook into the underlying XQuery/Saxon engine?

For example - my main thought is to run a local instance of Apache with a UI to control everything? I need to build this quickly so what sort of technology to build a web app PHP/Java/Ruby/GWT that plays nice with Saxon? What does everybody else do?

Bit of a high level question I know, so there is probably going to be more than one answer.

Answer (score 1):

Running a new Saxon instance for each test from a .bat file is certainly very inefficient - it incurs a lot of overhead initializing the Java VM.

We do the same process using a test driver (which we actually distribute) written in Java that contains the control logic you have in your bat file, calling Saxon via the s9api API (though you could use XQJ if you want to make it more portable). We produce the results in XML rather than HTML because it is more amenable to analysis, and we can always render the results for browser viewing when necessary - though usually we just look at the XML. There's also a version that runs with a Swing UI, but I rarely use that version.

If I were starting today I might consider writing such a test driver using XProc.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction @michael-kay - can you also tell me please: **1)** What is the name of test driver in your distro & where to reference it? **2)** Can the test driver be run as a servlet? **3)** I am using GWT to develop the WebApp & provide the upload function and results display UI - what Saxon JAR's would I need in my `CLASSPATH` to achieve what you have described? **4)** XProc looks very interesting esp `p:exec` that I assume can be used to call our external XML Parser & drive the process once raw results logs are uploaded to server ready for Parsing into XML.

Comment: Get the saxon-resources download from the SourceForge page, and look for drivers/java/com/saxonica/testdriver/XQueryTestSuiteDriver.java

Comment: Thanks I will find that -  does this have an example of hooking in XProc too?

Comment: No, we haven't attempted XProc. I would if I were starting again.

Comment: I see, yes would be good. Is there an XProc processor that can be programatically controlled and can also hook into Saxon?

Comment: Yes looks good - have downloaded. Any idea if Orbeon (CE) would give me unzip (oxf:unzip), exec (oxf:execute-processor) and saxon (oxf:xquery) out the box?